# Working of Login System in Large Applications

Tags: authentication

I am crazy to know that, how login system works in large applications like Facebook, Gmail, youtube, yahoo etc. Once after entering credentials server is responding more quickly. How is that possible ?

There must be more db servers for storing user information. So my question is

1. How they look for authentication information over more db servers?
2. Do they look over all the db servers to check for a particular user and if so how it is responding more quickly ?
3. Do they allocate db server based on geographical location of the user ?
4. And do they also have more application servers and how these are interconnected with  each other.

Comment: its better if close votes have comments too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. RDBMS have the functionality to link servers that issue distributed queries, updates, commands, and transactions on heterogeneous data sources.
2. The database system will use some form of cached information about the user, in SQL Server an execution plan is stored and used when a query is executed. The database management system will decide which execution plan to take in order to generate the fastest results or use a cached data set.  Note: Google, Facebook, Amazon etc will lot of server processing power behind the scenes which will make it seem instantaneous.  They will also have dedicated teams to manage their databases, perform indexes, tuning, optimization and identify bottlenecks.
3. The geographical location of the server could be a factor.  The closer the server is to the user the faster they can get the information but IMO this would be a matter of nano/milli seconds difference depending on where their data center is located. If the server gets too busy then the load balance will migrate you/other users to a server with more available resources.
4. Yes.  Using more than one web server is needed in scenarios like this and is tied in to part 3 of the question, which server you hit depends on how much available resources the closest server has and if it will accept your connection.  They are distributed but the whole process seems transparent to the user, i.e. they think they are using the same server as every other client.  They can be interconnected by using session management, Web Services and other interoperability techniques and technologies.